# NOT able to connect with mysql jdbc from springboot after activating ssl

Tags: ssl

NOT able to connect with jdbc from springboot after activating ssl
activated mysql ssl
created key using mysql_ssl_rsa_setup
added to my.cnf
created springboot keystore.p12 using hostinger certificate
after that I created trustkeystore using same file that I added in jvm environment
after all these still getting  error

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:/var/www/html/jksDirectory/ [Invalid keystore format]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:/var/www/html/jksDirectory/ [Invalid keystore format]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format**

Comment: I want to ask I havent created using openssl... my springboot keystore is not self certified.. it is generate using domain.crt file provided by hostinger.. if I generate key using openssl.. willl it work..

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please, take your time to edit your question: use a proper format, include the question in the question body and not in a comment and generally try to write having in mind other people have to read it and *understand* it. We don't know what you are doing.